# How to round off numbers in SQL Server database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column (named PercentageDifference) with numbers that have decimal places as shown below:

```
PercentageDifference

1.886792452830100
2.325581395348800
2.758620689655100
-3.689320388349500
-0.284900284900200
0.400000000000000
```

I want a query to round off the numbers to the nearest 10 and then leave 2 decimal places.
Here is the output am looking for:

```
PercentageDifference
    1.89
    2.33
    2.76
   -3.69
   -0.28
    0.40
```

I have tried to use the ROUND function but its not giving me the expected results:

```
select round([Percentage Difference], 2, 1) from Table
```

How can this be achieved?

Comment: Try: SELECT CAST(ROUND(1.886792452830100,2) AS NUMERIC(17,2))

Comment: Can you give the results that is not expected from the results you have  ?

Comment: @nexus `FROM dual` -> Oracle

Comment: Just edited, my mistake @lad2025

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need only [CAST](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql):

```
SELECT CAST([Percentage Difference] AS decimal(19,2)) FROM Table;
```